# Uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Ability on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I have a rails 4 application successfully running locally with cancan. But when I push it to Heroku, I get this error, each time the code tries to authorize anything

```
Uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Ability
```

Looking at the logs, it looks like its failing in this method, which I have in my application controller. Any idea what is going on?

```
  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, load_service_provider_from_host)
  end
```

This works fine on my local machine.

Comment: anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what the issue is. The issue was, my ability class file was named **Ability.rb**. Note the upper case. When I changed it to lower case (**ability.rb**), just like all the other models, it worked fine. It still would be nice to know why this failed only on heroku and not locally.